# Calepin : mot courant ou non ?

Tags: usage

L'autre jour j'ai voulu expliquer pourquoi les rotations finies ne peuvent pas être représentées par des vecteurs. J'ai utilisé une visualisation classique :

[image]

J'ai dit aux étudiants :

> Prenons un calepin...

J'ai constaté que certains n'ont pas reconnu le mot. Plusieurs m'ont dit que c'est un mot vieux et plutôt désuet. Est-ce vrai ? Si c'est le cas quelle pourrait être la raison pour cela ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Désuet ? C'est un mot que j'utilise personnellement souvent, en tous les cas plusieurs fois par semaine. Je l'utilise aussi au sens figuré dans le sens de « je mets ça dans ma tête ».
C'est vrai que je suis très loin d'avoir l'âge de tes étudiants, alors question de génération peut-être ? Les étudiants de nos jours ne prennent plus de notes dans un calepin mais sur une tablette ou un smartphone ?

L'article [calepin de Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calepin) semble bien confirmer que ce soit le cas. On y trouve un paragraphe sur les bloc-notes numériques.

Il n'est pas (encore ?) noté comme vieilli dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*<sup>1</sup>.

On vend encore des calepins, en [France](https://www.easyflyer.fr/bureautique/carnet-notes/calepin-a5-marksman.html), au [Canada](https://cafr.blueline.com/produits-de-notes/blocs-steno-et-calepins.html)... Certes le mot « carnet » est plus utilisé.

Et certains utilisent encore des calepins pour prendre leurs notes comme le montre cette nouvelle parue récemment :

> Une femme de 42 ans a perdu son sang-froid après avoir oublié un calepin dans le train, ce lundi 23 septembre 2019, à Grenoble.

([Voir l'incident sur France3 Grenoble](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/auvergne-rhone-alpes/isere/grenoble/elle-oublie-son-calepin-train-finie-garde-vue-grenoble-1726941.html), mais il a été repris ailleurs dans la presse).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Il n'est par contre plus utilisé dans le sens où il était utilisé par la police pour parler de « recueil de  renseignements ». (Toujours d'après le DCLF).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Si des étudiants francophones n'ont pas reconnu le mot, c'est bien qu'il ne fait pas ou plus partie de leur vocabulaire, et donc qu'il est susceptible de devenir désuet pour un plus grand nombre de locuteurs.

Google Ngram ne confirme cependant pas cette tendance, car le mot est certes peu fréquent mais son usage à l'écrit apparaît en légère augmentation jusqu'en 2008 :

[image]

Je connais le mot ***calepin*** depuis « toujours » mais je pense ne jamais l'avoir utilisé spontanément, choisissant plutôt, suivant le cas, ***cahier***, ***carnet***, ***bloc***, ***bloc-notes***, ***agenda*** ou ***journal***.

<sub>Certains de tes étudiants ne comprendront plus la blague :</sub>  
<sub>— Comment appelle-t-on un nain qui sort d'une boulangerie ?</sub>
<sub>— Un agenda ... car c'est le petit qu'a le pain...</sub>